# What does $\sqrt{2i}$ imply in a question?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

While doing a certain problem based on complex numbers I faced this doubt.

When $\sqrt{2i}$ is mentioned in a question should I take it's value as $(1+i)$ or both  $(1+i)$ and $(-1-i)$ ?I mean should I take only the positive root or both the roots?

Well this is a very basic level doubt but I think its good to have clear concepts :-P

Comment: See "branch cut". Basically-it must be specified.

Comment: @ZacharySelk Isn't there any standard notation?Like$\sqrt{}$ for positive root and $-\sqrt{}$ for negative root?

Comment: Generally, $\sqrt{~~}$ will output the *principle* root.  Where $z=re^{i\theta}$ with $r\in\Bbb R^+\cup \{0\}$ and $0\leq \theta<2\pi$ you will have $\sqrt{z}=\sqrt{r}\cdot e^{i\theta/2}$, that is by squarerooting the argument will be halved.  $\sqrt{2i}=1+i$.

Comment: No, but if you saw $\sqrt{2i}$ in a book are you sure it wasn't $\sqrt{2}i$? That would make more sense, since the former is ambiguous.

Comment: Actually the question was to simplify $\sqrt{9+40i} + \sqrt{9-40i}$ in the form $a+ib$. @user4894

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks.That seems reasonable :-).But from where did you learn that?I never found it in any book!

Comment: @ZOZ Note that $i=e^{i\pi/2}$ as well as $i=e^{i5\pi/2}$.  The requirement that we use the representation with $0\leq \theta<2\pi$ and $r\geq 0$ will remove the ambiguity (*as otherwise, half of the argument of $\frac{5\pi}{2}$ would be $\frac{5\pi}{4}$, yielding the answer of $(-1-i)$*)

Comment: What do you mean by "squre of a complex number"?It hasn't been defined but some calculators do it.But $x^2=2i$ is defined as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** the same things said here apply to any multi-valued function $z \in \Bbb C^* \mapsto z^c$, where $c \in \Bbb C$.

We have for $z \in \Bbb C^*$,

$$\sqrt z := \exp(\frac12 \log z)$$

where $\log$ is the multi-valued logarithm function. So, the correspondence $z \mapsto \sqrt z$ is not a function, but a multi-valued function.

The multi-valued logarithm function is defined, on $\Bbb C^*$, as $\log z = \ln|z| + i \arg z$, where $\arg$ is the multi-valued argument function.

By Euler's formula, each non-zero complex number $z$ can be written as:

$$z = r(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)$$

for some unique $r > 0$, called the modulus of $z$, and for some unique (up to addition of $2\pi$) real number $\theta$. The multi-valued argument function is defined for such a $z$ by $\arg z =  \{\theta + 2k \pi, k \in \Bbb Z\}$.

It is a basic result that for any $\alpha \in \Bbb R$, $\arg$ assigns to any non-zero complex number a unique value in $[\alpha, \alpha + 2\pi)$. So, the correspondence $\arg_{\alpha}$, which associates to each $z \in \Bbb C^*$ the unique value of $\arg$ in $[\alpha, \alpha + 2\pi)$, is a function. Note that any such $\arg_{\alpha}$ is continuous on $\Bbb C$ except on the ray $\{z = |z|\exp(i\alpha)\}$. The principal argument is defined as $\text{Arg} = \arg_{-\pi}$ (some define it as $\arg_{0}$ and some even take $(\alpha, \alpha + 2\pi]$; these are just technical issues).

For any $\alpha$, $\arg_{\alpha}$ gives rise to a $\log_{\alpha}$ defined in the obvious way: $\ln|z| + i \arg_{\alpha} (z)$. So, we finally get a true function, call it $P_{\alpha}$, defined by $P_{\alpha}(z) = \exp(\frac12 \log_{\alpha} z)$.

Had we chosen $\alpha = -\pi$, we would have got:

$$\sqrt{2i} = P_{\alpha}(2i) = \exp(\frac12(\ln|2i| + i \text{Arg}(2i)) = 1 + i$$

and had we chosen $\alpha = \pi$, we would have got:

$$\sqrt{2i} = P_{\alpha}(2i) = \exp(\frac12(\ln|2i| + i \arg_{\alpha}(2i)) = -(1 + i)$$

This is why we can't meaningfully just talk about the square root of a complex number, but we have to specify an $\alpha$.

Usually, though, $\sqrt z$ is interpreted as $P_{- \pi}$.